# How to call a custom control's method through a command in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working with custom control which displays 3D rendered data to the user. The control has a ResetView() method which returns the state of the control to its defaults. I have a view model which is the data context for the window, so how would i call the control's ResetView method when a button is clicked in the same view and maintain the MVVM structure?

Comment: `button.Click` and `control.ResetView()` don't involve VM at all. you can do `control.ResetView()` in Click handler in code behind since it is internal view  operation.

Comment: on the 2nd thought, if contol is bound to VM, Vm probably should have `Reset` method and expose `ResetCommand` for button.Command binding

Comment: yeah I'm aware that button clicks are non-MVVM, by click I was meaning the commnd that is bound to the button

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind, nor does it mean no event handlers.  UI concerns should be handled in the UI and not artificially routed through a view model.  View models should take user input (via bindings and commands), interpret them, perform actions based on the interpretation, and then update their state with the results of these interpretations.  They shouldn't be doing any UI work.

Comment: That's the kind of thinking I am coming around to as I become more experienced. Would you say it is bad practice to call a control's method from the code behind of a user control that contains it? Assuming that the method call would no effect on any data presented to the user.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach that I typically use:

Create a property of type IObservable in your view model. You can
use Subject from Reactive Extensions (RX) as an actual
implementation.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Subject<Unit> _resetRequest = new Subject<Unit>();

    public IObservable<Unit> ResetRequest
    {
        get { return _resetRequest; }
    }
}
```

Create a behavior for the control. The behavior must
be bound to your property and subscribe to the observable. Call your
control's ResetView() method from the subscription OnNext handler.

```
public class ResetViewBehavior : Behavior<YourControl>
{
    private IDisposable _subscription;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RequestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Request", typeof(IObservable<Unit>), typeof(ResetViewBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnRequestChanged));

    public IObservable<Unit> Request
    {
        get { return (IObservable<Unit>)GetValue(RequestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RequestProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnRequestChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         ((ResetViewBehavior)d).Resubscribe();
    }

    private void Resubscribe()
    {
        _subscription?.Dispose();
        _subscription = Request?.Subscribe(_ => AssociatedObject.ResetView());
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        Resubscribe();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        _subscription?.Dispose();
    }

}
```

In XAML:

```
   <Window>
        <YourControl>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:ResetViewBehavior Request="{Binding ResetRequest}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </YourControl>
    </Window>
```

Call your subject's OnNext method from view model when you want to reset the view.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Subject<Unit> _resetRequest = new Subject<Unit>();

    public IObservable<Unit> ResetRequest
    {
        get { return _resetRequest; }
    }

    private void ResetView()
    {
        _resetRequest.OnNext(new Unit());
    }
}
```

With this approach you do not have code behind, which personally I always try to avoid in MVVM. Instead you incapsulate your logic in the reusable behavior.

You can also pass some data to the control's methods if you use some other class rather than Unit as IObservable parameter.

Comment: Many thanks for this, I will have a look into implementing it.